# How to fix “Cannot read property 'icons' of null” error?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, plugins

First of all, I'd like to mention [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/180098/85453) is not related, I'm using Drupal 8.6.1.

I'm trying to create a CKEditor plugin with a new button. In the */admin/config/content* page I get the error but the button appears well:

[image: Error in console but icon appears]

However when I go to */node/add/article* page, I get the error and there is a display issue on CKEditor windows:

[image]

Clearing the cache does not change anything.
The error does not appear anymore when I uninstall my custom D8 module.

---

*modules/custom/inline_comment/js/plugins/inline_comment/plugin.js*

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('comment', {

    icons: 'comment', 

    // The plugin initialization logic goes inside this method.
    init: function (editor) {
        // Define the editor command that add a comment.
        editor.addCommand('comment', {
            // Define the function that will be fired when the command is executed.
            exec: function (editor) {
                ...
            }
        });

        // Create the toolbar button that executes the above command.
        editor.ui.addButton('Comment', {
            label: 'Add comment',
            command: 'comment',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        });
```

---

*modules/custom/inline_comment/src/Plugin/CKEditorPlugin/InlineComment.php*

```
namespace Drupal\inline_comment\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin;

use Drupal\ckeditor\CKEditorPluginBase;
use Drupal\ckeditor\CKEditorPluginConfigurableInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor;

/**
 * Defines the "inline_comment" plugin.
 *
 * @CKEditorPlugin(
 *   id = "inline_comment",
 *   label = @Translation("CKEditor Inline Comment")
 * )
 */
class InlineComment extends CKEditorPluginBase implements CKEditorPluginConfigurableInterface {

  public function getFile() {
    return drupal_get_path('module', 'inline_comment') . '/js/plugins/inline_comment/plugin.js';
  }

  public function getButtons() {
    return [
      'Comment' => [
        'label' => t('Linkit'),
        'image' => drupal_get_path('module', 'inline_comment') . '/js/plugins/inline_comment/icons/comment.png',
      ],
    ];
  }
```

---

The location of the icon is: `modules/custom/inline_comment/js/plugins/inline_comment/icons/comment.png`

Comment: IIRC the plugin IDs need to match, currently there's a disparity between `inline_comment` and `comment`

Comment: Good catch @Clive. Feel free to write it as an answer to make me able to accept it ;)

Answer (score 3):

To anyone who is running into this issue:

```
 * Defines the "inline_comment" plugin.
 *
 * @CKEditorPlugin(
 *   id = "machine_name_that_must_match_with_icons",
 *   label = @Translation("CKEditor Inline Comment")
 * )
 */
```

and

`getButtons()` must return the same ID.

Annotation is new to me and I am sure it's not new to anyone else who are Drupal 8 developers but it might help someone who is new/still learning about how Drupal 8 works.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/plugin-api/annotations-based-plugins

Comment: Ugh ... poor proofreading on my part strikes again. Thanks!

Comment: It's more than just ensuring that the @CKEditorPlugin ID matches the object that is returned from the public function getButtons(). You must also make sure that the JS that is called by public function getFile() registers a plugin with the same ID as well.